# 2 player turnbased game logic

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

JS noob here..  I am trying to come up with a barebones multiplayer turnbased card game. with my current coding knowledge, i can implement according to the following pseudo code..

i have 3 files, index.html, multiplayer.php, gameStatus.txt.

```
  index.html:
      player one clicks ready button, which sends 1 to multiplayer.php.  
      player two clicks ready button, which sends 1 to multiplayer.php. 
      every 1 sec, repeater() checks if "twoPlayerFound" is returned from multiplayer.php.
          if "twoPlayerFound" is returned, 
              then console.log("two players are online, game begins..")
          else 
              console.log("waiting for another player to join..")

  multiplayer.php:
      when 1 is posted from index.html, php checks gameStatus.txt
          if gameStatus.txt has 0
              then overwrite gameStatus.txt 0 with 1;
          else if gameStatus.txt has 1
              then overwrite gameStatus.txt 1 with 2;
              send to index.html "twoPlayerFound"

  gameStatus.txt:
      either has 0,1, or 2
```

Q1.  how can i reset automatically gameStatus.txt to 0 if the players are no longer online.
Q2.  what would be the problems using this implementations? 
Q3. Is this the correct way of thinking multiplayer game setup

Thanks..

Comment: Hello... If you are trying to learn coding the approach is kinda fine. But if you are trying to pull off a 'fully functional' realtime application, I believe, it's better to invest your time in something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2):

- Q3 - I don't think this is a great way to implement a multi player game setup, why? check answers for Q2.
- Q2 - Your file can't handle all the complex scenarios that might came up during the full implementation of the game.

An example: 'How can I reset automatically gameStatus.txt to 0 if the players are no longer online'(yes, that's your Q1), to solve this problem, you should keep a time stamp for each player and update timestamp each time the player contact the server and keep a loop to keep an eye on these time stamps and eliminate the player who haven't contacted you recently. To implement this you have to keep some ID to identify your players and so on...

Also, think about how would you be able to scale this setup,scenarios such as: More than 2 people connecting to your server at once, people trying to play in pair with people they like.

Your game also feels network hungry. What you are trying to do is called AJAX Polling.

My suggestions? For client side, make use of WebSockets in HTML5, also try to do some research on socket.io. Most people would recommend nodejs for backend, but you can also make use of PHP. You should also choose a method to implement sessions for users and game status(this choice very much dependent of your backend tech. stack).